# SSDT SSRS How to show Report values greater than zero

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, sql-server-data-tools

I have Productivity float value, which a calculation:  **Sum(Fields!TotalMinutes.Value)/Sum(Fields!ProductiveHours.Value*60)**

This value has some zeroes:
[Productivity with zeroes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mi2S.jpg)
Is there way in SSDT Visual studio to filter them out?
Or should I use an expression?

I tried the following in the expression box:
=switch(Sum(Fields!TotalMinutes.Value)/Sum(Fields!ProductiveHours.Value*60)>0, 
 Fields!GLProgramName.Value)

But the Program Name space is still there, with an empty spaces...
My goal is to filter out Programs with zero values..

Thank you!

Comment: use custom code to do division.. if the denominator is 0 you will get an error.. obviously!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out grouped zero values in a CTE (common table expression) in your SQL statement.

```
WITH
sample_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Program1', 30, 2)
    , ( 'Program1', 45, 1)
    , ( 'Program3', 15, 5)
    , ( 'Program3', 10, 7)
    , ( 'Program5', 0, 8)
    ) tbl ([GLProgramName], [TotalMinutes], [ProductiveHours]) 
)
, 
group_sample_data
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [GLProgramName]
    FROM 
        sample_data
    GROUP BY
        [GLProgramName]
    HAVING  
        SUM([TotalMinutes]) / SUM([ProductiveHours]) * 60 != 0 
)
SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE [GLProgramName] IN(SELECT [GLProgramName] FROM group_sample_data)
```

Also, I would recommend doing your calculation for productive minutes in your SQL or create it as a view to then use in your reports.

```
WITH
sample_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 'Program1', 30, 2)
    , ( 'Program1', 45, 1)
    , ( 'Program3', 15, 5)
    , ( 'Program3', 10, 7)
    , ( 'Program5', 0, 8)
    ) tbl ([GLProgramName], [TotalMinutes], [ProductiveHours]) 
)
SELECT 
      [GLProgramName]
    , [TotalMinutes] = ISNULL([TotalMinutes], 0)
    , [ProductiveHours] = ISNULL([ProductiveHours], 0)
    , [ProductiveMinutes] = ISNULL([ProductiveHours], 0) * 60
FROM 
    sample_data
```